# Two trigonometry homework problems - details appreciated!

Tags: trigonometry

I'd appreciate a solution to these two related problems with a figure, if possible. I understand that it may involve trigonometry, but I can't be completely sure.

1. John is buying a 6 foot tall Christmas tree. The car is only 4 foot long at the back. At what angle should they place the tree to fit it into the car?

I think it should involve a right angled triangle with hypotenuse 6 ft and base 4 ft. So the angle $\theta$ should be given by $cos \theta = 4/6 = 2/3.$ **Is it correct?**

2. Estimate, if with an internal height of 1 meter, the car is tall enough to get the tree home? **I've no idea what to do here - any help appreciated?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For part 1 your solution sounds fine. For part 2, imagine again your right angled triangle. If its base is 4m, what is its height? Will it fit in a trunk that's 1m tall?

Comment: Thanks, but I'm confused about 'internal height' - what do they mean by that? Also, the back is 4 foot, not 4 meter. Can you specify a right angled triangle with the necessary figures 4 foot, 1 meter, 6 meter etc? I'm having trouble visualizing it

Comment: @Stat_math They just mean the height measured on the inside of the trunk. The "internal" is just there to indicate that this is the actual amount of room that you have, as opposed to the "outer" measurement which may include factors like the thickness of the ceiling of the car.

Answer (score 1):

The question is essentially testing your skills in trigonometry. Here I will provide solutions to both of your questions to help you understand.

For both questions, we're looking at how to put a Christmas tree in a car which is only four feet long, and yet the tree itself is 6 feet long. Hence, it should be clear that we can't just lay it flat; the car is simply not long enough.

Instead, we can raise the tree on an angle.
Both parts will use the following diagram:
[image]

In this diagram, the **internal** height of the car is $h$, the hypotenuse is the tree which is being propped up within the car, the base is the actual length of the car and $\theta$ is the angle the tree is propped up.

Question 1: This is simply asking at what angle we must prop the tree for it to fit within the car, *with no concerns about the height of the car*.
Therefore, we need to find $\theta$.
By trigonometry, $\mathbb{cos}(\theta) = \frac{4}{6} = 2/3$.
Hence $\theta = \mathbb{cos}^{-1}(2/3)$ and one computes this as being just about 48 degrees. Thus, you were correct in your first question.

Question 2: All this question is asking is whether, given our required angle determined from Question 1, the tree will fit in the car if it has an internal height of 1 m (that is, if in the car you measure from the floor to the ceiling a distance of 1 m).

This is simply a matter of solving for $h$.
So, again by trigonometry, $\mathbb{sin}(\theta) = \frac{h}{6}$ so that $h = 6\mathbb{sin}(\theta) = 6\mathbb{sin}(48) = 4.4$ feet (roughly).

Now, each meter has about 3.3 feet, and thus 4.4 feet is about 1.3 meters.
This means that for the tree to fit in the car it must be raised higher than the car itself can support on the inside, and therefore the car is not tall enough to get the tree home.